# Using Ajax with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My assignment was to make two separate paragraphs hide and show using jQuery. I have done this successfully. Our next step is to add in JavaScript Ajax code in order to allow the two paragraphs to show and hide. I have thus created two separate html files in order to accomplish this.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to display both paragraphs at once. Either one only shows up or one paragraph appears twice, so in both divs.

Thank you!

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){
    if (xhr.status === 200){
        document.getElementById('get').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        document.getElementById('set').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'Share.html', true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.open('GET', 'Network.html', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: your _xhr.onload_ function is setting the same response text to both divs. Create two separate _xhr_ calls (named differently), and use a single div inside each to set the innerHTML from responseText.

Comment: Thank you as well! I've just started to learn Ajax and now its much clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in your `onload` callback of the xhr request, you're setting both the `get` and `set` elements with the same response text, which is why one paragraph appears twice.

Create two different `XMLHttpRequest` objects and have different onload handlers.

Or if you're using jQuery, why not look into the [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method?

```
$("#get").load("Share.html");

$("#set").load("Network.html");
```

Comment: Ah it worked! Thank you so much, simple fix but I obviously needed the help haha :)